# Compiler cannot infer return type

Tags: swift, generics

Swift is unable to infer the return type of a function, whose parameter is a closure, and where the return type is deduced from the closure´s return type.

Given this generic class:

```
class Bar<T> {
    init(_ v:T) {}

    func wrap<R>(f:()->R) -> Bar<R> {
        return Bar<R>(f())
    }
    func wrap(f:()->()) -> () {
        f()
    }
}
```

The function `wrap` is overloaded, once taking a Closure as parameter which returns `()`, and another time taking a Closure as parameter which returns a type specified as a type parameter (`R`) for the function.

In the following snippet, it seems obvious that the return type of the Closure passed as an argument to the function `wrap` is a `String`:

```
var bar :Bar<Int> = Bar<Int>(0)

let b0 = bar.wrap {
    return ""
}
```

IMHO, the compiler should now be able to deduce the return type of `wrap` as type `Bar<String>`, and thus should be able to infer the type of the constant `b0` accordingly.

The compiler (as of beta 3) issues the following errors:

```
main.swift:53:16: error: type '()' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'
    return ""
           ^
main.swift:51:9: warning: constant 'b0' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected
let b0 = bar.wrap {
    ^
main.swift:51:9: note: add an explicit type annotation to silence this warning
let b0 = bar.wrap {
    ^
      : ()
```

Either of this workaround would fix the issue:

```
let b1 = bar.wrap {
    () -> String in
    return ""
}
let b2:Bar<String> = bar.wrap {
    return ""
}
```

**Edit:**  added Antonio's answer as another version which compiles correctly:

```
let b0 = bar.wrap { "" }
```

**The question is:**

Is there a compelling reason for the compiler not being able to infer the return type in the failing examples, assuming it is working as specified?

Again, please consider this:

```
works: let b0 = bar.wrap { 0 }
fails: let b0 = bar.wrap { return 0 }
```

Or, is this possibly the effect of an incomplete or incorrect implementation of a beta status compiler?

Note: Please, do not state your opinions here, only clear facts - if any. ;)

Comment: I believe that there's any documentation for such an in depth question. Please post this in the apple dev forums, and maybe the LLVM guys will answer you.

Comment: @mindw0rk I've posted this issue also in the official dev forum: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/236473

Answer (score 5):

Maybe what you're looking for is the implicit return from single expression closure:

```
let b0 = bar.wrap { "" }
```

**Addendum**

There might be a lot to say for one method to work and not the other.
The book doesn't make any mention of a shortcut using just `return` and a value. But that works when expliciting the generic type

```
let b2:Bar<String> = bar.wrap { return "" }
```

On the other hand, in the [Inferring Type from Context](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_114) paragraph of the swift book, when talking about type inference there's no mention of generics, so I wouldn't be surprised if type inference doesn't work when combined with generic types in this case.

Keeping reading book:

> This parameter is expecting a function of type (String, String) -> Bool. This means that the String, String, and Bool types do not need to be written as part of the closure expression’s definition

That doesn't mean (but it could) that this won't work:

```
() -> (T)
```

where `T` is a generic type.

That said, I think that

```
let b0 = bar.wrap { return "" }
```

doesn't work because there's a generic type involved in the equation. **What follows is my opinion**, but you should read it anyway. It's possible that this:

```
let b0 = bar.wrap { "" }
```

works but it shouldn't. Meaning that it works, but it's a bug, it should produce a compiler error. Does that make any sense?

Comment: This snippet actually will compile - and confirming with the debugger, it seems to compile as expected. However, it raises even more questions: why is `let b = bar.wrap{""}` different than `let b = bar.wrap{ return ""}`. And btw, this weird behavior is not dependent on the return type of the closure: works: `let b = bar.wrap{ 0 }` issues error: `let b = bar.wrap{ return 0}`. That all seems to indicate an issue in the compiler. Thanks anyway +1 ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: I know, you wrote about avoiding opinions, but that might change the way you look at the problem

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. Regarding generics vs concrete types: it should´t matter, as long as the generic types are deducible and the generic is syntactically correct given the constraints set for the generic types. So, in other words, it should´t matter whether you have a concrete type `String` or a generic type `T`. And, if you would have an expression `t1 == t1`, where both variables are of type T, then you additionally need type constraints (e.g.: Comparable).

Comment: In order to answer your final question whether `let b0 = bar.wrap { "" }` should compile: yes, it _could_ be a bug and it should not compile - since it _could_ be that the type T is not deducible (from the closure itself), and thus the compiler needs a type information from elsewhere. ;)  However, (IMHO) I think the compiler should be able to deduce the type from the closure expression. ;)