# Under what situation Swift Cannot infer the type to be use?

Tags: swift, type-inference

> Swift can almost always infer the type to be used for the constant or variables if you provide an initial value.

That's what the official document claimed. It said "Almost Always" but not "Always". What is this tiny not always case looks like? Can you give me an example that the Swift cannot infer the type without annotation?

This is a very edge equation, but I'm curious, I would like to know.

Many thanks

Comment: The main place I've seen it be unable to infer is when using nested or complex generics. e.g. changing several ".map"s together

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980322/swift-cannot-infer-type-from-context/26720578

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788884/compiler-cannot-infer-return-type

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Thanks for the example

Comment: @Asdrubal Thanks for the resources

Comment: `var arr = []` if Foundation is not imported.  Same with `var dict = [:]`

Comment: `func foo() -> Double {
    return M_PI
}

func foo() -> Int {
    return 17
}

let result = foo()`